# Title and Text hides behind my slider when zooming in to the page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

i am currently building a wordpress page and encountered to a problem:
when i zoom in, the title and text of the container under the slider (revolution slider) hides behind my slider. I think this problem could be solved with some lines of css. In the posted image you can see my problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp1KN.jpg on 100% zoom
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hhup.jpg on 110% zoom

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without any code, but I can guess you have a fix top margin (`px` unit) or equivalent on your title tag. Instead use another size unit (`%`) for example.

Hope this helps. Can't do much without seeing any code.

Comment: Hey thank you for your fast answer! I just solved the problem with some design options in the page builder.